# Sort array keys ascending

Tags: php, arrays

If I assign values to array like this:

```
$foo[0] = 2;
$foo[1] = 3;
print_r($foo);
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
)
```

But if I do:

```
$foo[1] = 3;
$foo[0] = 2 ;
print_r($foo);
```

I get:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 3
    [0] => 2
)
```

As you can see first goes array with index 1 and it confuses me, is it possible to make that it would start from 0

*If you interested, I assign value to array with index 1 because I need to use that value for calculating array with index 0*

Comment: What is your exact problem? I doubt that `print_r` is the final use you have for that `$foo`. Could it be that this is a presentation issue only? If you access `$foo[0]` you'll still get the same result, sorted or not. You  could ofcourse use the `ksort()` option provided in the answers, but first consider if you need it.

Comment: @Nanne just for debugging, I will remove them, but it's really annoying, because in all other examples it goes from 0 and there it's from 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to use [ksort();](http://php.net/ksort). It sorts your keys ascending

```
<?php
$foo[1] = 3;
$foo[0] = 2 ;
ksort($foo);
print_r($foo);
```

results in

```
Array ( 
   [0] => 2 
   [1] => 3 
)
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/7d0a2)

Comment: Perhaps an explanation of why Templar sees the behavior he sees, and then maybe an explanation of what `ksort()` does would be helpful.

Comment: @Templar: because it should be sorted first. This function returns boolean

Comment: You can check the manual: `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.` that line prints that returnvalue (probably `true`), and not the sorted array

Comment: Because ksort returns a boolean. You have to call ksort and then afterwords do a `print_r` on the array. The argument is passed as reference.

Comment: Yeah, you guys are too fast ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

The reason it is like this in PHP, is because arrays are a bit different from arrays in other languages. Arrays in PHP are somewhat similar to HashMaps in Java and Dictionaries in C#, although still a bit different.

Comment: @genesis, speed doesn't matter so much as quality.

Comment: @genesis, at least he provided some explanation of what was happening.

Answer (score -3):

You can also add

```
$foo[0] = '';
```

,before you add any value to $foo[1]

Comment: It is not what he wants. he said "HOW to sort array keys"... not "HOW to workaround it"