# How to sort an array based on key first?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to first sort an array and then displaying it alphabetical order

```
   $testArray[test] = 'London';
    $testArray[fsee] = 'Cardiff';
    $testArray[pol] = 'Edinburgh';
    $testArray[bede] = 'Manchester';
    asort($testArray);
    foreach ($testArray as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ' -- ' . $value . '<br/>';
    }
```

And i like to alphabetical sort on test, fsee, pol and bede, so it return

```
bede -- Manchester
fsee -- Cardiff
pol -- Edinburgh
test -- London
```

Comment: Side note: Make sure your keys are wrapped in at least single quotes when you assign them. Otherwise php has to determine if they are constants first, and then fallback to assuming its not. Throws lots of warnings too with full error reporting on.

Comment: here is an example like your question look this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7388926/4499393

Comment: @IncredibleHat  i am using the following in my php loop and now i am not sure if i need to set $label in single quotes ` if (!array_key_exists($label, $sums)) {
                        $sums[$label] = 0;
                    }`

Comment: @alex No. Variables you do not, as they are known as a $variable. Its when you do: `$stuff[ something ]` that it does not know if `something` is a constant, or a string to use (like your example code you provided in the Q) `$testArray[test]` should really be written as `$testArray['test']` .. if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ksort` function.

```
ksort($testArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a very fast sorting ignoring the keys case (your keys seem to be all lower case so a case-insensitive comparison should be good in this situation), use this:

```
uksort($testArray, "strnatcasecmp");
```